# Sent text shows email address instead of phone number on IPad

Tags: ipad, email

Under IMessage were it states "You can be reached by IMessage at" it shows my email with a checkmark beside it. I can send text but not receive and sent text shows my email instead of phone number. It worked great at one time but something changed, probably by me! If I tap on the email it does not give me the option to use my phone number.

Comment: Does your iPad have a SIM installed?

Comment: To send SMS (green message) from an iPad both devices must be using the same AppleId.  Are you using the same AppleId on both devices?

Comment: The IPad is Wi-Fi only. I forgot to mention that and yes I’m using the same Apple ID. It use to work correctly so that makes me think I changed a setting but I have tried everything I can think of.